# Oracle SQL Developer Remote access

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a complete newbie to Oracle SQL Developer and I'm trying to make my database accessible remotely. I have a virtualbox setup with my database and I can access it in My Sql Developer through my OS and through my linux image but having trouble getting others to. I think I may not have it configured correctly to allow other users to access it. I have created usernames and passwords but the hostname and port information I either don't have setup correctly or I have the wrong information. Hostname is telling me is localhost.localdomain which doesn't seem right. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the DB listener is listening on the network ip and not 127.0.0.1.. Also that firewalls are configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

The host port needs to be forwarded to the VM's port. Here's the VBoxManage command to do that.

```
$VBoxManage modifyvm "Oracle Developer Days"  --natpf1 "tns,tcp,127.0.0.1,1521,,1521"
```

Then 'localhost' will work from the host

```
$ sqlplus system/oracle@//**<<<<hostip address>>>**:1521/orcl
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Sep 24 11:29:03 2010
Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select 1 from dual;
  1
----------
  1
```

Then it's up to your machine's firewall settings to allow other machines to connect to your host on that port.